# How can I convert a list of strings to list of dictionaries without using zip function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I convert a list of strings to a list of dictionaries without using the zip function:

```py
DomainesSavoie = [
    ["Portes du soleil", "Les trois vallees", "Paradiski"], 
    [280, 343, 235],
    [650, 600, 425]
]
```

to the forme:

```py
[
    {"Nom": "Portes du soleil”, "nbPistes": 280, "nbKms": 650}, 
    {"Nom": "Les trois vallees", "nbPistes": 343, "nbKms": 600} ,
    ...
]
```

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: Where exactly in your current attempt did you get stuck?

Comment: def to_list_of_dicts (tab):
  nouvelle_liste =[]
  list_of_keys=["nom","nbPistes","nbKms"]
  dico = {}
  for i in range(len(tab)):
    dico [list_of_keys[i]] = tab[i][i]
    nouvelle_liste.append(dico)
  return nouvelle_liste
print(to_list_of_dicts(l))     this is my function it is false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is as edited, you can do such a thing with:

```py
l = [
    ["Portes du soleil", "Les trois vallees", "Paradiski"],
    [280, 343, 235],
    [650, 600, 425],
]
new = [{"Nom": l[0][i], "nbPistes": l[1][i], "nbKms": l[2][i]} for i in range(3)]
print(new)
```

which yields:

```
[{'Nom': 'Portes du soleil', 'nbPistes': 280, 'nbKms': 650}, {'Nom': 'Les trois vallees', 'nbPistes': 343, 'nbKms': 600}, {'Nom': 'Paradiski', 'nbPistes': 235, 'nbKms': 425}]
```

---

This can also be done, if you need a loop and function, this way:

```py
def to_list_of_dicts(l):
    lod = []
    for i in range(3):
        lod.append({"Nom": l[0][i], "nbPistes": l[1][i], "nbKms": l[2][i]})
    return lod

print(to_list_of_dicts(l))
```

Comment: but in using loops

Comment: Write a function that transforms such arrays into a dictionary array. Each dictionary will represent a ski resort with attributes: name, nbPistes and nbKms

Comment: It doesn't seem like you have put any effort into this at all. I think I satisfied what was the initial intent. If you need more information, so does the community. Update you question to clarify all of the requirements and then show what you have attempted and what issue you are facing.

Comment: thanks , that's what i mean thank u